# IDP / SSO - How to sync local users accross multiple client apps?

Tags: authentication, websocket, oauth-2.0, synchronization, single-sign-on

I'm building an Identity Data Provider (IDP) to centralize my users' accounts and provide them with Single Sign On (SSO).

The goal is to allow our clients to navigate through our applications without having to reauthenticate and find their data back.

We built that central service with Laravel Passport. Authentication and SSO are working fine. Our applications retrieve users' data and store local user records for their own custom needs, filled with data from IDP.

But now, the question is : **how should we keep local user records up-to-date with the IDP ?**

We already set up a syncing mechanism driven by users' activity. But we'd like to go further and have a mechanism not based on user's activity. The goal is to be able to update an application local user on IDP data updates without having the user logging in the client app.

I can't imagine our central IDP sending requests to each application's API. I guess it's better being "one direction only", from client apps to IDP.

I was thinking about a "broadcasting" method based on websockets. The central IDP could send "user update" messages through a websocket. Clients apps could listen to this websocket and update their local records if needed.

What do you think about that ? Any experience feedbacks on that topic ?

Thanks for your help